# How to tell if Target.Value is double or string

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-interop

I am working with an Excel sheet in a VSTO project.

I am using the event

```
Excel.Worksheet.Change(Range Target)
```

It gives a Target object of Excel.Range. I want to check whether this Target has a string or double value by using

```
Target.Value
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm...maybe try

```
object obj = Target.Value;
MessageBox.Show(obj.GetType().ToString());
```